# Firebase push notification using node js and polymer web app

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification, polymer

I want to send device push notification to android app. Here is what I am doing:

1. Created a webapp server(node js) and client code is written in polymer.
2. Deploying this webapp to android device as android app using some third party android container([Predix Mobile](https://github.com/PredixDev/PredixMobileSDK)).
3. The third party container takes the web app and deployed it into android device as android app.
4. The third party web app doesn't have any plugin which can generate device token used to send device push notification using google firebase.
5. I have a login page in my web app, when I login, I want to generate the device token. But I can't find any help how to do that, because my client code is written in [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/).
6. I will send that token to my server code which will be deployed to cloud, the server will do a post call to push the notification to device.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: take a look at your original question here --> https://forum.predix.io/questions/22048/android-device-push-notification-plugin-in-predix.html?childToView=22066#answer-22066

Answer (score 0):

I used OneSignal to do something similar in a project. 
https://onesignal.com/

Your UI loads in a webview and you have full control of the MainActivity. In your micro service, you can make a call to the OneSignal API with the message you want to send as a push notification. You can handle the push notification in your MainActivity. You can send notifications to a specific device, a group of devices, or all devices running the app.

You can create an interface between your MainActivity and Polymer WebView to move data between them.

https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html